Async to speed up Core ML Model prediction but got BAD_ACCESS
I've developed a Core ML prediction app for macOS. It functions correctly, but the prediction time is twice as long as what Xcode's performance report indicates.
I watched a WWDC video that mentioned async would accelerate prediction speed, so I attempted to use the async method to improve performance. However, it consistently results in a BAD_ACCESS error, and I'm unable to determine where the crash occurs.
Below is the code that outlines the flow from ScreenCaptureKit CMSampleBuffer.imageBuffer input runModel() -> resize CVPixelBuffer using Metal -> Prediction -> setRenderData into Metal Renderer:
func runModel(on pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
    
    guard let surface = getIOSurface(from: pixelBuffer) else { return }
    
    Task {
        guard let result = try? await self.performInference(surface) else { return }

        await ScreenRecorder.shared
            .setRenderDataNormalized(surface: surface, depthData: result)
    }
}


func performInference(_ surface: IOSurface) async throws ->[Float]? {
        
    try Task.checkCancellation()
    
    guard let model = mlmodel else {return nil}

    // get CVPixelBuffer from IOSurface
    var px: Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>?
    let status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithIOSurface(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                    surface,
                                                    nil,
                                                    &px)
    guard status == kCVReturnSuccess, let px2 = px?.takeRetainedValue() else { return nil }
    
    // Resize input image
    guard let data = metalResizeFrame(sourcePixelFrame: px2,
                                        targetSize: MTLSize.init(width: InputWidth, height: InputHeight, depth: 1),
                                        resizeMode: .scaleToFill) else {
        os_log("Preprocessing failed", type: .error)
        return nil
    }
    
    // Async Model Predict
    let input = model_smallInput(input: data)
    let prediction = try await model.model.prediction(from: input)
    
    // Get result into format
    var results: [Float] = []
    if let output = prediction.featureValue(for: "output")?.multiArrayValue {
        if let bufferPointer = try? UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>(output) {
            results = Array(bufferPointer)
        }
    }
    
    return results
}

I've tried adding IOSurfaces to an array to keep them alive before completing the flow, but it still crashes.
Given my situation, should I avoid using async prediction? Should the Screen-Capture stream with Model prediction always be synchronous? If so, how can I speed up the prediction speed?

Update 2024-10-15
Below is the list of the function names with parameters in order of execution:

createFrame(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) 
    runModel(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer)
        await performInference(surface: IOSurface)
            - metalResizeFrame(sourcePixelFrame: CVPixelBuffer, targetSize: MTLSize, resizeMode: ResizeMode)
            - await model.prediction(input: ModelInput)
        await setRenderDataNormalized(surface: IOSurface, depthData: [Float])


And the BAD_ACCESS happened that XCode shows below that I didn't call the method:


Update 2024-10-15 (2)
I use ScreenCaptureKit sample that async capture screen. When I do the await in one flow, it might lead to crash that the second captured screen is inputted.

can you please provide the list of only function names with parameters in order of execution? and which is the starting point for this execution?

I've updated the code and add the list that ordered by execution. The metalResizeFrame() convert CVPixelBuffer into texture and resize with waitUntilCompleted().
